# Create a custom node tab with a custom path

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, menu

Is there anyway I can customize the paths to a node's tabs?

When using either pathauto or hook_menu_alter, I can change the path to the node view to from node/node_id to, well pretty much anything, but let's say xyz/node_title.

The node tabs, however, still stay with the path /node/node_id/tab_name

I'm trying to add a custom tab to the node, and keep the custom path as well (e.g.: xyz/node_title/tab_name instead of node/node_id/tab_name).

I manage to add the custom tab via hook_menu:

```
$items['node/%node/members'] = array(  
    'title' => 'Manage Membership',  
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_members',  
    'page arguments' => array(1),  
    'access callback'   => 'mymembers_members_access',  
    'access arguments' => array(1),  
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK  
);
```

but if I try to customize the path, either at hook_menu or at hook_menu_alter, the tab just disappears.

Any ideas?

PS, I've posted [the same question](http://drupal.org/node/832234) on the Drupal forums, no answer so far. I'll cross-update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add two functions in settings.php: [custom_url_rewrite_inbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6), and [custom_url_rewrite_outbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/custom_url_rewrite_outbound/6).

The examples in those pages should make clear how to use them.

```
function custom_url_rewrite_inbound(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
  global $user;

  // Change all article/x requests to node/x
  if (preg_match('|^article(/.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
    $result = 'node'. $matches[1];
  }
  // Redirect a path called 'e' to the user's profile edit page.
  if ($path == 'e') {
    $result = 'user/'. $user->uid .'/edit';
  }
}

function custom_url_rewrite_outbound(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  global $user;

  // Change all 'node' to 'article'.
  if (preg_match('|^node(/.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
    $path = 'article'. $matches[1];
  }
  // Create a path called 'e' which lands the user on her profile edit page.
  if ($path == 'user/'. $user->uid .'/edit') {
    $path = 'e';
  }
}
```

Drupal 7 uses two new hooks, instead of those functions: [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) and [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7).

Comment: I ended up using this answer, together with url_alter module (which allows me to keep settings.php clean).
The subpath_alias module colided with other custom code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, what does Drupal 7 uses?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, if you want to earn some extra reputation, you can asnwer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743071/use-node-menu-on-page :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this module will help you form the tab path the way you want: [Sub-path URL Aliases](http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias).