# Use node-menu on page

Tags: drupal, menu

I would like to use the node-menu (see image) on a page in Drupal.

[image]

Is this possible and, if yes, how?

Comment: do u mean you want to have a new tab ?

Comment: No, I want to add this tap on a place where it doesn't appear...

Comment: u can add tabs  using the hook_menu()

Comment: Is it a node page, or some other kind of page (like a view)?

Comment: Yup, I did use `hook_menu()`, and the links are showing on `/node/7` but not on my custom generated `my-profile`... How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page you are referring is a custom page output from your module, and "mymodule/page" is the path for that page, for which you want the tabs "View" and "Edit," then you should implement `hook_menu()` using code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['mymodule/page'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page_view', 
    'access arguments' => array('view mymodule page'),
  );

  $items['mymodule/page/view'] = array(
    'title' => 'View', 
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK, 
    'weight' => -10,
  );
  $items['mymodule/page/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit', 
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page_edit', 
    'access arguments' => array('edit mymodule page'), 
    'weight' => 0, 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
  );

  return $items;
}
```

If the page you are referring is a page that is shown at example.com/mymodule/page, and that should show what you see at example.com/node/7, then you can implement the following code, in Drupal 7:

```
function mymodule_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language) {
  if (preg_match('|^mymodule/page|', $path)) {
    $path = 'node/7';
  }
}
```

The equivalent for Drupal 6 is writing the following code in the settings.php file:

```
function custom_url_rewrite_inbound(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
  if (preg_match('|^mymodule/page|', $path)) {
    $result = 'node/7';
  }
}
```

I didn't write the symmetric code for `hook_url_outbound_alter()`, and `custom_url_rewrite_outbound()` as I suppose you are not interested in rewriting example.com/node/7 to make it appear as example.com/mymodule/page, but you are interested in making appear example.com/mymodule/page the same as example.com/node/7.

Answer (score 1):

Okay; a node page usually has those View and Edit tabs. So my next question is to wonder why they aren't appearing on your node page already. Have you by chance created a custom page template for this node type and removed the code that prints the tabs? Or is there a chance you're logged in as a user that doesn't have permission to edit this type of node?

There must be a reason why you're not getting those tabs; they should be there, by default.

If you do have a custom page template for this node type, look for code that looks something like this:

```
        <?php if ($tabs): ?>
          <div class="tabs"><?php print $tabs; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

If you don't see code like that, try adding it.

If you DO see code like that, try to isolate what's different about this content type compared to other content types where you DO see those tabs.

Comment: The page is a custum URL page. So, the `$tabs`-thing you just described is present, but for some reason, the tabs aren't showing on the page